# C# and Visual Studio WSDL Addon for SOAP - i can't add certificate, or its added but in wrong way

Tags: c#, ssl, soap, wsdl

I generated code with visual studio addon from some `wsdl` and `xsd` files.

[image of adding wsdl i dont know name of this addon.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVEa4.jpg)

I cant post here these files, because of NDA, but i have a methods like:

```
B2BGetAcctServicePortTypeClient cli = new B2BGetAcctServicePortTypeClient();

X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("../../../Certs/pathTo.p12", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);


// 1st:
cli.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;

//2nd:
cli.ChannelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;

//3rd:
cli.ChannelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = cert;
```

This 3 variable allows me to add `X509Certificate2` and I tried each of them, but no one works.

I'm sure that certificate is good because when I'm requesting in the traditional way with `System.Net` requests and client it looks fine, I don't have error (i will post error content at the end of this question). 
I need to use generated classes because it is a lot of data which I will send. I don't want to make human mistakes, this is software for my client, not for me, so I really need to use visual studio addon to generate my reference code.

So, i tried second way to add this certificate:

```
cli.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate.Import("../../../Certs/pathTo.p12", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);
```

with every flags available in X509KeyStorageFlags, but it always gives me

```
NullReferenceException
```

with

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Error i got in first example:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'ADDRESS'.) ---> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'ADDRESS'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A security error occurred
```

I'm done with my ideas to solve that, and my experience with certificates is the low middle, so please, give me advice.

Anyway, I tried to add certs from my certs storage (local, and machine) the same result.

Ps. certificate was tested in Google Chrome, and i can make a GET request without any problem. Secure connection is estabilished, so im really sure of certificate correction.

Comment: Don't you need to add more than 1 certificate?